# Perl - Pseudo-hashes are deprecated

Tags: linux, perl, api, perl-module

I am trying to get d request through perl. But i m getting below error :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/usr/packages/perl/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3";
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;
use MIME::Base64;

my $url = 'https://example.com:8443/cli/agentCLI';
my $credentials = encode_base64('username:password');

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts =>{ verify_hostname => 0});
my $response = $ua->get($url, 'Authorization' =>" Basic $credentials");

die 'http status: ' . $response->code . '  ' . $response->message
unless ($response->is_success);

my $json_obj = JSON->new->utf8->decode($response->content);

# the number of rows returned will be in the 'rowCount' propery
print $json_obj->{rowCount} . " rows:n";

# and the rows array will be in the 'rows' property.
foreach my $row(@{$json_obj->{rows}}){
    #Results from this particular query have a "Key" and a "Value"
    print $row->{Key} . ":" . $row->{Value} . "n";
 }
```

output ( error ) :

Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at agent.pl line 21.
No such pseudo-hash field "rowCount" at agent.pl line 21.

Thanks,
Kalaiyarasan

Comment: Evidently the JSON isn't decoding as you expect. Try dumping the result (`use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($json_obj);` to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: PS, `/usr/packages/perl/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3` should be `/usr/packages/perl/perl-5.16.3/lib`. `use lib $dir;` will look for arch subdirs (`$dir/$archname`, `$dir/$version` and `$dir/$version/$archname`) and add those as well.

Answer (score 1):

See:

http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlref.html#Pseudo-hashes%3A-Using-an-array-as-a-hash

In the recent version: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Pseudo-hashes%3a-Using-an-array-as-a-hash

This is deprecated. I would imagine ( but can't tell without your JSON) that your JSON top level is an array.

`Data::Dumper` can help tell you what your actual data structure is.